# Cell Output for variable sum

Tags: excel, vba

Code appears to be running smoothly, I am now just having an issue with the output of the sum and color once it has been calculated, I am trying to print the outputs to the "SC" worksheet so they can be further analysed. So the Output in the new worksheet should build a matrix with the irrelevant values (sum or value <1) 0 and the sum values shown in the respective cell.

```
Private Sub MC()
    Dim c&, i&, j&
    Worksheets("SC").Cells.Clear
    For j = 1 To Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 1 To Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, j) > 0 Then
                c = RGB(Int(Rnd * 255) + 1, Int(Rnd * 255) + 1, Int(Rnd * 255) + 1)
               'Debug.Print "Testing value at: " & Cells(i, j).Address & vbLf & "Cone sum: " & SumAndColorCone(Cells(i, j), c) & vbLf
               Worksheets("SC").Cells(i, j) = "Testing value at: " & Cells(i, j).Address & vbLf & "Cone sum: " & SumAndColorCone(Cells(i, j), c) & vbLf

            Else: If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, j) <= "0" Then Worksheets("SC").Cells(i, j) = "0"

            End If

        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Function SumAndColorCone(r As Range, color&) As Double
    Dim i&, k&, c As Range
    Set c = r
    For i = r.Row - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If r.Column - k < 2 Then
            Set c = Union(c, r(-k, -r.Column + 2).Resize(, r.Column + k + 1))
        Else
            Set c = Union(c, r(-k, -k).Resize(, (k + 1) * 2 + 1))
        End If
        k = k + 1
    Next
    SumAndColorCone = Application.Sum(c)
    If SumAndColorCone > 1 Then c.Interior.color = color
    'If value of sum is less than 1 return "0"
    If SumAndColorCone < 1 Then SumAndColorCone = "0"
End Function
```

Comment: "I am now just having an issue" - always helps to explain exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub MC()
    Dim c&, i&, j&
    Worksheets("SC").Cells.Clear
    For j = 1 To Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 1 To Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, j) > 0 Then
                c = RGB(Int(Rnd * 255) + 1, Int(Rnd * 255) + 1, Int(Rnd * 255) + 1)
                Worksheets("SC").Cells(i, j) = SumAndColorCone(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, j), c, Worksheets("SC"))
            Else
                If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, j) <= "0" Then Worksheets("SC").Cells(i, j) = "0"
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Function SumAndColorCone(r As Range, Color&, wsColor As Worksheet) As Double
    Dim i&, k&, c As Range
    Set c = r
    For i = r.Row - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If r.Column - k < 2 Then
            Set c = Union(c, r(-k, -r.Column + 2).Resize(, r.Column + k + 1))
        Else
            Set c = Union(c, r(-k, -k).Resize(, (k + 1) * 2 + 1))
        End If
        k = k + 1
    Next
    SumAndColorCone = Application.Sum(c)
    If SumAndColorCone >= 1 Then
        wsColor.Range(c.Address).Interior.Color = Color
    Else
        SumAndColorCone = 0
    End If
End Function
```